# Does LOT strictly control hand luggage weight?

Tags: hand-luggage, lot-polish-airlines

I have a bag which complies with LOT's hand luggage dimensions, but it will be a couple of kilos over their 8kg quota.

Is LOT known for strictly checking the hand luggage weight? Checked in luggage is free, but I'd rather just have a carry-on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I flew with LOT last summer from Tbilisi to London via Warsaw and then back. At no point did anyone even attempt to weight my carry on backpack.  They asked me whether I had any carry on - I showed my backpack over my shoulder - and they just said, "Ok".

My bag was probably at or slightly over the 8 kg limit.

That said, it really depends on how unlucky you are.  In my experience they were very lenient, but that was almost a year ago and only in my specific experience.

Comment: Confirmed - the check-in crew didn't even have any weights, so they probably don't weigh any luggage.